# How to manage Apache Superset Filterbox queries on large database?

Tags: data-analysis, business-intelligence, apache-superset

Apache Superset Filterbox is a functionality that allows users to add filters dynamically on graphs - and that on dashboards. It works great for query that can be executed in less than a minute, but I don't understand how to deal with query that can take more than 2 ~ 3 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

FilterBox [soon to be deprecated] can be pointed to the fact table (it'll generate a `SELECT DISTINCT {dimension} FROM {table} LIMIT 10000`). There's a field in the dataset configuration modal that enables you to add a predicate to filter / limit the scan. For large tables we recommend filtering on time on an indexed or partitioned field.

[image: Filter predicate]

It's also possible to point the Filter Box to a table that isn't the large fact table in favor of a reference or dimension table where the SELECT DISTINCT is much cheaper. The requirement there is for the field name to be the same for the filter to propagate properly on other charts in the dashboard.